# Clicar num sinalzinho de + e aparecer mais inputs

Tags: javascript, html

Haveria alguma forma de um usuário ao clicar em uma pequena imagem com um sinal de +, adicionar mais inputs aos formulário. No caso eu tenho os seguintes inputs:

```html
Identificação do Responsável da Empresa 1: <input type="text" name="socio1"><br><br>
Número de Identificação Civil do Responsável da Empresa 1: <input type="text" name="socio1"><br><br>
Nif do Responsável da Empresa 1: <input type="text" name="socio1"><br><br>
Identificação do Responsável da Empresa 2: <input type="text" name="socio1"><br><br>
```

Assim colocaria uma imagem com um sinal de + e ao clicar nessa imagem apareciam mais 3 inputs mas com os names diferentes.

Como poderia fazer isso?

Comment: Estou marcando como duplicata porque a resposta lá na outra pergunta explica bem como fazer isso. Se tiver alguma dúvida, pode ser o caso de editar e reabrir está pergunta, ou fazer uma nova mais específica.

Answer (score 3):

HTML

```
<button id="add">
+
</button>
<ul id="list">
</ul>
```

JavaScript

```
var add = document.getElementById('add');

add.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
  var newInput = document.createElement('input');
  var newListItem = document.createElement('li');
  newListItem.appendChild(newInput);
  var list = document.getElementById('list');
  list.appendChild(newListItem);
});
```

Live: https://jsfiddle.net/tx0xf059/

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="display:none;padding:15px;border:1px solid #CCC;" id="3inp">
<input name="a" type="text" value="input 1"/>
<input name="b" type="text" value="input 2"/>
<input name="c" type="text" value="input 3"/>
</div>
<div onclick="clicou();" style="padding:15px;border:1px solid #CCC;"> + </div>
<script>
function clicou(){
document.getElementById("3inp").style.display = 'block';
}
</script>
```

Comment: Parece que você entendeu errado a pergunta.